# I'm not able to connect proxy host database in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-settings, django-database, django-postgresql

after running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Got the Error port 5432 failed: FATAL:  Feature not supported: RDS Proxy currently doesn’t support command-line options.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DATABASE_NAME',
        'USER': 'DATABASE_USER'
        'PASSWORD': 'DATABASE_PASSWORD'
        'HOST': 'PROXY_HOST',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': f"-c search_path={DATABASE_SCHEMA}"
        },
    }
}
```

After commented OPTIONS -- {DATABASE_SCHEMA}

```
 models already migrated in particular schema but schema is not detected.


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DATABASE_NAME',
        'USER': 'DATABASE_USER'
        'PASSWORD': 'DATABASE_PASSWORD'
        'HOST': 'PROXY_HOST',
        'PORT': '5432',
        # 'OPTIONS': {
        #     'options': f"-c search_path={DATABASE_SCHEMA}"
        # },
    }
}
```

so finally getting migrations error because it's pointing to the database not particular schema

```
You have 178 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): **address, analytics, etc...**
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
February 09, 2023 - 15:42:20
Django version 3.2.9, using settings 'MoreProjectAPI.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

it's not connected my schema could any one please suggest how can i fix this issue in root level not in every model level.

Answer (score 0):

hi your server output after commenting looks fine, try migrating first as it suggests!

```bash
python manage.py migrate
```

or
`python3 manage.py migrate`

or simply

`./manage.py migrate`

and then run your server

Comment: tables are already there only thing database host is  proxy host not normal host so proxy host ,  RDS Proxy currently doesn’t support command-line option to select schema name